# Embed html into an existing div

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

When the html is returned from django views

```
   <script>
   //The following is in the ready function
   $("#data").html("{{dict.html}}");
   </script>
    <div id="data" name="data" style="display:block;"></div>
```

The following html is displayed on the screen.How to embed this html into data div

```
     <ul ><li ><a ><ins> </ins>Ses</a><ul ><li>
```

Comment: If the rendered code coming out correctly inside that script tag?  Also why not just put the template inside to begin with, avoiding JavaScript?

Comment: Does your HTML code in dict.html contain any newlines?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the safe filter

```
$('#data').html({{dict.html|safe}});
```